# How do you generate classes from XAML in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xaml, expression-blend

How do you generate classes from XAML in Visual Studio 2008?

I have a Silverlight project.  The XAML has been written in Expression Blend.  I am told that I can use Visual Studio to use the grid classes in the Page.xaml file (the whole solution is loaded into Visual Studio) to generate the .CS (C#) files in Visual Studio 2008 that correspond to the several  classes in the XAML.  How is this done?  Is there a wizzard somewhere that will do this for me?  Do I have to do this by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bit confused by your description, as creating XAML in Expression blend normally creates the code-behind (.cs) files at the same time. The designers would actually have to go to extra trouble to create XAML files *not connected* to code-behind files.

Best check that you don't already have the code behind files and possibly change your question based on what you find.

It sounds like they actually wanted you to add [data?]grids to an existing layout. If so, that is a drag-drop from the toolbox in VS into the XAML view in VS 2008. VS 2008 does not support graphic editing.

If you can clarify your question I will try to clarify my answer to suit :)